# Problem with code drawing alternately shaded boxplot (ggplot2, R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, rectangles

I would like to draw alternate shades/rectangles in a boxplot, similar to the second image in this post:
[Adding shading alternate areas for categorical variable in a bar plot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592484/adding-shading-alternate-areas-for-categorical-variable-in-a-bar-plot-in-ggplot2?rq=1)

Below is my code using mtcars as an example. I transformed carb and cyl to factor to better match my real data and code

```
 library(ggplot2)
 odd_numbers <- seq(1,33,2)
 mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
 mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
 ggplot(mtcars) + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = cyl), position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
   geom_rect(data = mtcars, aes(x = carb, y = mpg), 
             xmin= as.numeric(mtcars$carb[odd_numbers]) - 0.5, 
             xmax = as.numeric(mtcars$carb[odd_numbers]) + 0.5, 
             ymin = -Inf, 
             ymax = Inf, fill='grey', alpha=0.5)
```

I thought the problem of the x-axis being numeric was solved in the code, but there is still a problem:

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x, y
>
> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (32): xmin, xmax

Might anyone have a suggestion, please? Thank you.

**EDIT**

Following comments, I edited the code, as per below:
- Removed `[odd_numbers]`
- Swapped order of `geom_boxplot` and `geom_rect`

Code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 odd_numbers <- seq(1,33,2)
 mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
 mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
 ggplot(mtcars) + 
   geom_rect(data = mtcars, aes(x = carb, y = mpg), 
         xmin= as.numeric(mtcars$carb) - 0.5, 
         xmax = as.numeric(mtcars$carb) + 0.5, 
         ymin = -Inf, 
         ymax = Inf, fill='grey', alpha=0.5) + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = cyl), position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

This results in the following, so not quite there yet. Thank you.

[image]

Desired result similar to this:

[image]

Comment: you are limiting the xmin/xmax to only the odd numbers (length 17) but your data is length 32. just remove the [odd_numbers] bit?

Comment: @RAB No, use `geom_rect(data = mtcars[odd_numbers, ]`. And swap `geom_rect` and `geom_boxplot` to have the boxes *over* the grey bars.

Comment: @RAB and Rui Barradas: Thank you for your suggestions. Please edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I say in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845260/problem-with-code-drawing-alternately-shaded-boxplot-ggplot2-r#comment100243072_56845260), the `data` argument and the other arguments must match in size. So extract only the `odd_numbers` from `mtcars` in the call to `geom_rect`. And there is no need to set `xmin` and `xmax` by subsetting `mtcars$carb`, use `odd_numbers` directly.
And swap the two geoms to have the boxes over the grey rectangles.
Note also that I have changed `odd_numbers` to go up to 32, not 33. One value after `nrow(mtcars)` would throw an error.

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

odd_numbers <- seq(1, 32, 2)

ggplot(mtcars) + 
   geom_rect(data = mtcars[odd_numbers, ], 
             xmin = odd_numbers - 0.5, 
             xmax = odd_numbers + 0.5, 
             ymin = -Inf,
             ymax = Inf, fill = 'grey', alpha = 0.5) +
   geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = cyl), 
                position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Rui Barradas. That's an improvement. However, the only other thing I would like to change is that each rectangle occurs alternating at x-axis categories 1, 3, 5, etc. (each with the width of one column, from -0.5 to +0.5), as per image referred to all the way on top of this page in original post. Thank you.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez So the problem now is that the bars are at 2, 4, 6, 8, not at odd numbers? See the edited code and graph.

Comment: Great edit! This is exactly what I hoped for. I do not mind whether rectangles are at even or odd, so this is perfect! Thank you so much!